# How To Scrap Network Type 'XHR' / 'Fetch' Data In Selenium 4?

Tags: java, selenium, rest, network-programming, google-chrome-devtools

### My goal

Im trying to scrap raw video stream data (.ts files) from [twitch.tv](https://www.twitch.tv/) using Selenium 4.
All live streams are fed in chunks of video,
I can access them manually by:

1. opening a chrome tab with a running [twitch.tv](https://www.twitch.tv/) livestream
2. open DevTools (F12)
3. go to Network tab > XHR
4. The stream of .ts (transport stream) files being fetched are my desired files.
5. I can just doubleclick on them and chrome downloads this small video chunk file.

I want to reproduce this using Selenium 4 but I have no experience with Web Programming (POST, Flow etc). My current programm
is able to scrap image files. But once the response received is of .ts file (XHR/Fetch) it returns.

> DevToolsException: {"id":11,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"No data found for resource with given identifier"},"sessionId":"79BA2C212FABA878DB3524D7D0F49BDC"}

### I have tried

Calling [Network.getResponseBody](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-responseReceived) when the [Network.loadingFinished](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-loadingFinished) event has fired but this also doesn't work. There is never the same requestID on either event.

Remarks: Im aware there is a Twitch API.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    InitializeSeleniumDrivers();
    driver.get("https://www.twitch.tv/thebausffs");
    
    
    DevTools devTools = ((ChromeDriver) driver).getDevTools();
    devTools.createSession();
    devTools.send(Network.clearBrowserCache());
    devTools.send(Network.setCacheDisabled(true));
    devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.of(100000000)));


    
    devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), responseReceived -> {

        RequestId requestId = responseReceived.getRequestId();
        
        try {
            Command<Network.GetResponseBodyResponse> getBody = Network.getResponseBody(requestId);
            Network.GetResponseBodyResponse response = devTools.send(getBody);
        } catch (DevToolsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
}
```

### Headers Example

**GENERAL**

```
Request URL: https://video-edge-c55dd0.ams02.abs.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/segment/CrEFZRTkEBMVDg5w4Ygn2pwqXKLGK5NAUAQ7ZWHeCORCjjFxfh9McgTBm_DTCvfP1MrZIg1jb2-oo2769tLAjFKjUd4AQaKtV3LeTEpPJyB_7ZAgolK-dSlLAqnC1xaI7z6iJCC4W1fb5RkkJmLk2D5nYEpyA17gSqe1eoB5zYsrDnal6Sm__B5LhxzOwTPOKI66jxXeIThm8tpaFGabccyd8AcT7RIfqCRv9Jas-IMQCqnBLLpIjk5rC-n4USQzLI6R4xGeTyTwMgX3BQ7EcxB-X62kUvsJm2O7Q2iJEI-ongDyyFRCapzo8iBtGgN2ruxvp8SeCKHO8j9NbS4jymG276ZigtnDXEQbxa6f5i9dHEcf9g1ump4RZtd48eOv6bPsGCDhFfULRd8adcM369ew90NrzyYbImQZnhFcnyqvfYIlCg-FFyjqJHVz37MZGc7TLbSh1YqmrkAClamXb8fFPGCXpsIrY-IDmKgTxh8tEmjbdacBWsKxxwJAOv-H6MUZB67MP1KMeT94YMjGXBcIjJo4JKeFCKoITCLJI4jjzqNmFa_efdlaJ89mUodxQRHJARV3qwdp04TSvZALBbOua6m-0T-01lOEYlr6w408mr5araj7c7gjpvrj_83jb0wqJG7ala1DBUg0U0Vx2rQxzumokyz66MxfMJy3ZSY92L-JdS47RjcOpilnpTI9bI8RPRyY4grds2SHDudWxgp-jJWgHdtbbFpuDCZENwOuU_-Agsf0lA_g59KnXnAuz59yovCO2C_O8ptkyoImgZ47qBPBIn-DDD-rzJloGD-GTQn4zGlmAFcg6GunjeW3PbHjKjMz8vA_K8NOF7ofO94YOtj_1khbCFGfH2_dF8zDwMSieR5Mvg7upQdzwgl_GAmf7OIAbHXwA1DqamnbAeWundcaDEM8dWDJF-pfTicm0CABKglldS13ZXN0LTIwtwQ.ts
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 185.42.204.31:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**RESPONSE HEADER**

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private
Content-Length: 1589164
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Sun, 14 Aug 2022 16:56:31 GMT
```

**REQUEST HEADER**

```
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Referer
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.81 Safari/537.36
```